# Terminology: What is sort?

Tags: logic, terminology, type-theory

My current understanding is that sorts are ranges of quantification.

> many-sorted logic (MSL) allows quantification over a variety of domains (called sorts) - [Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-many-sorted/)

[First-order Peano arithmetic(PA)](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Peano+arithmetic) has only one sort $N$, so it is single-sorted.

If I modify PA so that quantification over $\mathrm{Prop}$ is possible, is it two-sorted? Or, single-sorted second-order theory?

Comment: See [Second-order logic: Non-reducibility to first-order logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_logic#Non-reducibility_to_first-order_logic)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from the more philosophical examples in the Stanford Encylopedia of Philosophy (SEP), many-sorted logic (MSL) is useful in mathematics for giving formal languages that fit well with structures like vector spaces, where our intuition is that there are two kinds of object, scalars and vectors, which combine algebraically in a controlled way: if $x$ and $y$ are scalars and $v$ and $w$ are vectors, we have a well-defined notion of what $x + y$, $x\times y$, $v + w$ and $x\times v$ mean, but we view terms like $x + v$ and $v \times w$ as meaningless. MSL allows us to exclude these unwanted terms from the language. It is, however, just a convenience, we could work in a single-sorted language where the universe includes both scalars and vectors and we would have predicates to distinguish the two sorts of object.

However, I think you want your sort Prop to be a sort whose values ranges over propositions (truth-values) and you want to be able to use terms of type Prop to form formulas. E.g., you want to have formulas like $\forall p^{\Bbb{N} \to \mathrm{Prop}}\forall x^{\Bbb{N}}.p(x)$: this would be syntactically invalid in MSL - terms aren't formulas in the syntax of MSL. However, as the SEP article says, you can translate second-order logic (SOL) into MSL by adding a membership relation $\in$ and translating $p(x)$ into $x \in p$ (and similarly for properties on tuples - see the SEP article for details).

Whether this translation of SOL into MSL is satisfactory depends on your point of view about the meaning of SOL. The position most commmonly taken is that in SOL, when you quantify over formulas, you are quantifying over **all** properties that exist in the metalanguage you are working in (i.e., not just some set of properties that exist in some model). This is called **standard semantics** and is the point of view that leads to the assertion that [SOL cannot be reduced to FOL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_logic#Non-reducibility_to_first-order_logic) mentioned in the comments. An alternative idea is to allow a model to define what sets of properties it deals with. This idea leads to [**Henkin semantics**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_logic#Semantics) and leads to the opposite conclusion, that SOL can be reduced to FOL